# How to Limit web requests per second to avoid spamming and denial of service

Tags: java, tomcat, web, spam-prevention, denial-of-service

I have a web-page which takes user's search query and searches it in the database. As this query is time consuming, even with proper indexes in place, I want to limit the search requests to, say, 1 per 2 seconds per user. Currently I am using the following method(Rough sketch)

**LIMITATIONS:**
**1) There is no login system in my website. Rather, I am depending upon the request headers to get the ip address and user id of the user.**

**Algo:**

```
1) Maintain a map of ips and user ids and their latest search timestamp.
2) For every search request, 
   2.1) If user has searched in last two seconds: Show error message
   2.2) Else, allow him to search
```

I want to know is this method adequate? As both the ip address and user id is coming from the request header, is it possible for spammers to change the request headers?

Comment: its possible to change some request headers, but not the IP, when you think about it the IP is set on the Socket communication level.

Comment: @QuakeCore it is entirely possible, and quite common, to spoof an IP address, and I believe I would do it if I was to design a DDOS attack (which is not the case). Limiting the number of search per IP address will only disturb real users, and not deliberate attackers. But it could be a protection against unintentional user spamming.

Comment: A software trying to prevent a ddos attack wont help you much, because the attack would already hit your hardware, long before it reaches a vm language like Java.

Comment: @Stefan , The search query takes a second and a half on average. We just want to limit that, so that the application does not freeze. Just putting a safe check on developer's part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple servlet filter, that keep users from accessing resources for a period of time (might need improvement):

```
// (requires http sessions enabled)
public class AccessControlFilter implements Filter {

private final String ACCESS_CONTROL_SESSION_KEY = String.valueOf("NextAccessAllowedTime".hashCode());

// how long to prevent users from accessing in ms?
private final long penaltyTime = 1000 * 2;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // is http request?
    if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession();

        // has access value in session?
        Object value = session.getAttribute(ACCESS_CONTROL_SESSION_KEY);
        if (value != null) {

            Date nextAccessAllowed = new Date(((long) value));
            if (new Date().before(nextAccessAllowed)) {

                // handle access denied (better redirect to another url or display message then sending this response code?)
                ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access to this resource is denied until: " + nextAccessAllowed);
                res.flushBuffer();
                return;
            }
        }
        session.setAttribute(ACCESS_CONTROL_SESSION_KEY, System.currentTimeMillis() + penaltyTime);
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("Starting " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " on resource: \"" + config.getServletContext().getFilterRegistration(config.getFilterName()).getUrlPatternMappings().iterator().next() + "\" with penalty time: "
            + penaltyTime + "ms!");
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("Stopping " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
}
```

Enable it in web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>acf</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.package.AccessControlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>acf</filter-name>
    <!-- Resource to check. Should be the url your search form posts to! -->
    <url-pattern>/search/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you are looking for a module at http server level, have a look at "mod evasive".

Maybe you should try to cache your search results (i.e. ehcache) and create a *fixed* thread pool to handle the searches, so you are able to control the quantity of searches at a time.